# get the indexpath of the cell containing the view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, scroll

im trying to scroll to the a cell containing for example a specific uitextfield, **it works if the table has only one section**, but with **more than 1 section it doesnt scroll**, im using this extension

```
func indexPathForView(_ view: UIView) -> IndexPath?
    {
        let center = view.center
        guard let superview = view.superview else {
            let origin = self.convert(view.bounds.origin, from: view)
            let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: origin)
            return indexPath
        }
        let viewCenter = self.convert(center, from: superview)
        let indexPath = self.indexPathForRow(at: viewCenter)

        return indexPath
    }
```

thank you for your help

here are the values

when **i have 1 section** in the table

center:
▿ (294.0, 46.5)

- x : 294.0
- y : 46.5

viewCenter:
▿ (294.0, 309.5)

- x : 294.0
- y : 309.5

indexPath:
▿ some : 2 elements
- 0 : 0
- 1 : 2

when **i have 2 sections** in the table

center:
▿ (294.0, 46.5)

- x : 294.0
- y : 46.5

▿ (294.0, 1320.5)

- x : 294.0
- y : 1320.5

indexPath:
▿ some : 2 elements
- 0 : 1
- 1 : 4

it is the same cell, in the same section, but when i change the number of sctions at runtime this happens

Comment: What section do you get in indexPath ?

Comment: Because cells are reused, so the indexPath of the view might be in section 1 instead of section 2.

Comment: So of you select first cell of section 2, what do you get in indexPath : section 0, row: 0 ? What is the value of viewCenter ?

Comment: i updated the question with the values @claude31

Comment: i updated the question with the values @Larme

Comment: So it seems you get the correct section : indexPath: ▿ some : 2 elements - 0 : 1 - 1 : 4, that is fifth cell in second section. So maybe you would just need to scroll to the selected row ?

Comment: Show where you call `indexPathForView`, and what's the `view` (how do you set it) parameter.

Comment: @Larme it is the uitextfield, i call it this way, self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: self.tableView.indexPathForView(txtUsername)!, at: .top, animated: true)

Comment: Again, you seem to bypass an important concept in cells: *Cells are reused*. How do you call you method? How do you keep a reference on textField? Where did you do `txtUsername`? That's not how it should work. Instead, remember which indexPath has a UITextField, and scroll to it directly.

Comment: @Larme it is a static tableview, the uitextfield is an IBOutlet

Comment: anyone can help